# How do I access data in this javascript MAP object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, dictionary

I'm making an AJAX call which returns XML data, and this is my 'success:' function (callback):

```
success: function (data) { 
        var $rowArray = $(data).find("[nodeName=z:row]");
          $rowArray.each(function(index) { // for each date put it into calMap.
          calMap[$(this)[index].title] = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
          calMap[$(this)[index].date]  = $(this).attr("ows_EventDate");
          });
         }
```

**calMap** is a global javascript object declared outside of the function.

```
var calMap = {};
```

What I want to do is create a function where I can pass in a **title**, have it search **calMap** for that title, and if found, the specific object is returned and I'll be able to access the **date** property for that object.

Problem is, I can't seem to access the data I insert into the calMap object.  For starters, I just want to print the map.  Tried **eval**'ing it, tried alerting **calMap[0]**, tried alerting **calMap[0].title**, but nothing.  Can someone help me with this?  Thanks!

Update:
I want to do something like this:

```
var data = getData("myTitle");

function getData(title) {
// if title is in calMap, something like this?
var result = (calMap[title])); 
return result;  // returns an object or NOTHING
}
```

then i'll check if date is defined or not, and if it is, i'll access its properties (ie. **data.date**.  That make sense?

ANSWER:
I ended up using an array.  STILL think I should be able to use the object MAP, but needed to get my project done.

Here's the final code for the code that accesses the array items:

```
function hasCalDate(code)
{
    var matched = "";
    for (var f=0;f<calMap.length;f++){
        var re = new RegExp(code);
        if (re.test(calMap[f].title))
        {
        matched = calMap[f].title+','+calMap[f].date;
        }
    }
return matched;
};
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: try using console.log(calMap) in chrome or firebug first

Comment: Oh yes, the console was great.  Turned out I was getting an array of OBJECTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `calMap` as an *array* (i.e. square brackets, not curly ones):

```
var calMap = [];
```

Then, inside your `each` function, I'm guessing you want something more like

```
calMap.push({
    title: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
    date: $(this).attr("ows_EventDate")
});
```

Comment: Thanks Emmett, this WORKS -- but I was staying away from a straight array because I assume the searching of an array vs. an object would be less efficient.  Instead of looping over an entire array to find a title, I can just access the map with a key and get the properties, right?

Comment: @tres Near the end of your question, you stated that you were alerting `calmap[0]` and `calMap[0].title` (which is array syntax), so I deduced that you were trying to create an array. Also, what sorts of keys are you hoping to access the properties with?

Comment: @ Emmet - Yeah, sorry for the confusion.  I was just trying different things, but definitely wanted to use 'objects'.  I want to say:  calMap['myTitle'] and get access to calMap.date for that particular object that it matches (if it exists).  I'll update my post for what I want to do...give me a sec..

Comment: @tres Your properties have to be uniquely named. The way it seems like you're imagining it, you'll be overwriting the same two properties in every iteration of the `each` function.

Comment: @ Emmet - Hmm...  they are aren't they?  For each row I find in my success function I want to create an object with a title and a date, and store the object in calMap.  Thats why I was trying to reference calMap[0].title -- to get the title from the first object.  That make more sense?

Comment: @tres I'm still pretty sure you want an array. You'll be able access a value, e.g. `calMap[6].date`, in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `success` function is only run when your AJAX request completes. If you want to access `calMap` safely, you need to do so *inside* your callback.

Comment: My success function runs fine.  All it does is populate calMap.  The other functions should have access to that data afterwards.

Comment: @tresstylez Yes, it runs fine, but because it runs asynchronously, you cannot be certain when it has completed while in your main thread of execution. That's why callbacks exist, because they're only called when the request is finished.

Comment: I don't think this assumption was correct.  The main thread called the ajax function, the array/object was populated, and the main thread was able to access the array (the entire array).  I just didn't know how to access each item individually...  I'll update my code.